# Redirect to URL in iframe based on range of values in text box

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, range, comparison-operators

Hi I'm trying to set up a RSVP page but having some issues as some guests are invited for event 1, some for event 2 and others for both events. I'm trying to be diplomatic and set up different RSVP forms for each sort of guest.

I was hoping to do the following:
- Have a pop-up or just a page which invites guests to enter a number (found on invitation card).
- Based on the value entered, the guest will be redirected to a specific page. (eg, nos 0001 - 1000 redirects to page one, 1001 - 2000 redirects to page two, etc)

I've seen a few answers but they are all for a specific value and not for a range (eg. enter '123' and it directs to 'url.com/123'). Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to separate each group:

```
  function iframe_url(path)
     {
     if (/[0][0-9][0-9][0-9]|1000/.test(path) )
       {
       window.frames[0].location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
       }
     else if (/[1][0-9][0-9][1-9]|2000/.test(path) )
       {
       window.frames[0].location.href = "http://meta.stackoverflow.com";
       }
     }

   iframe_url("1000") //stackoverflow.com
   iframe_url("1999") //meta.stackoverflow.com
```

Remainder checking using the modulus operator will work as well:

```
  function iframe_url(path)
     {
     if (1000 % path < 1000)
       {
       window.frames[0].location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
       }
     else if (2000 % path < 2000)
       {
       window.frames[0].location.href = "http://meta.stackoverflow.com";
       }
     }
```